# Reload matched image

Tags: jquery

I'm testing if an img's src attribute matches a certain string. When it does I expect it to change the src attribute and make the image reload.

So far I've tried this but it is not working:

```
$('img').error(function(){
    if($(this).attr('src') == 'some_img_url.jpg'){
        $(this).attr('src', 'site_media/banner.jpg?_=' + Math.random());
    }
});
```

Any idea why this is not working?

edit:

It was a url problem just like NAVEED said, it works now,  I'm using jquery 1.5.1

Comment: Check the path of your new image. Its not looking a correct path.

Comment: What version of jQuery? Version 1.6 recently changed how the `attr` method works.

Answer (score 0):

this `error` function is called if the element was not loaded correctly http://api.jquery.com/error/ so the function will not be called if not an error happens. Put alert in your function and check whether it is called.

Answer (score 0):

It's not getting called, because the error event will not be wired up to the handler function before the browser throws the error event. http://api.jquery.com/error/ - look at the example and the reason they loaded the img src with JQuery.